# GTK+ 3.0 in C on Linux: handle multiple calls of callback function by signals

Tags: c, linux, callback, gtk, signals

Within my GTK+ application, an instance of GtkFileChooserWidget is permanently visible. By selecting files (single click), the user might process a file. This is done by the callback function switch_file().

```
g_signal_connect (chooser, "selection-changed", G_CALLBACK (switch_file), gs);
```

The function switch_file() is sometimes slow as it waits for user response in modal dialogs. Everything works fine unless a file which is currently selected in the FileChooser is deleted (by the application itself or any other process on the system). The FileChooser, which obviously runs in an own thread, submits then a secondary call to switch_file() which leads to a mess. I tried to prevent the multiple calls by using a mutex:

```
static void switch_file (GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
   info_t *gs = data;
   int err;

   if ((err = pthread_mutex_lock (&gs->mutex)))
      DebugExit ("pthread_mutex_lock(): %s", strerror (err));

   /* ... */
}
```

However, all calls to the callback function are done within the same thread on the same stack. So, the second call to pthread_mutex_lock() fails (PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK_NP is used) and lets the process exit.

Is there a possibility to postpone the calls to the callback function while switch_file() is working? For user events (key presses) it already works but not for signals caused in parallel by deletes files.

If the signals cannot be postponed: What would be a signal-safe solution to collect all selected files and process them subsequently (within the main thread)?

Comment: Temporarily disconnect the signal when you enter switch_file()? Reconnect on exit?

Comment: You cannot run GTK+ on multiple threads. You must confine all GTK+ stuff to a single thread. Get rid of your other thread. That the wrong answer has become "obvious" is starting to scare me.

Comment: @Chimera Disconnecting the signal would involve loosing some changes of the selection. But I'll try this if there is no other solution.

Comment: @andlabs I do not start any threads explicitly. Obviously, GtkFileChooserWidget runs in a separate thread. However, I have no influence upon this.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what exactly you want to solve... Do you want to stop users from being able to delete files while the dialog is open? And why are you handling selections as the user selects them, instead of after dismissing the dialog?

Comment: @andlabs I agree that I don't use the GtkFileChooserWidget in the standard way. Probably, this makes it more complicate. The file tree of this widget is permanently shown like in a file explorer. The deletion is done the application itself but might happen externally as well.

Comment: @Chimera Now I use `g_signal_handlers_block_by_func()` and `g_signal_handlers_unblock_by_func()` at the very beginning and end of the callback function, respectively. This stops the signals of the GtkFileChooserWidget thread which obverses the directory of the file system. Calling `gtk_file_chooser_set_filename()` in addition restores the initially selected directory entry. I'm not sure whether a call of `g_signal_handlers_unblock_by_func()` blocks signals as precise (in respect of time) as `pthread_mutex_lock()` does for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the best solution is to ignore the signal. I am not sure whether the following solution is absolutely safe but it works.

```
static int switch_ignore = false;

static void switch_file (GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
   info_t *gs = data;

   if (switch_ignore)
      return;

   switch_ignore = true;

   /* Do some work on the file system. */

   switch_ignore = false;
}
```